# how use jquery in response of ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

i use jquery-ajax and have three file.
my file is :

> jquery-1.8.3.min.js
>
> index.html
>
> res.html

`jquery-1.8.3.min.js` file is main of jquery file.
index.html code is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({url:'res.html',type:"POST",data:'',success:function(result){
                        $("#responsediv").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#state_id').change(function(){
                    alert($(this).val());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="responsediv">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and res.html code is :

```
<select id="state_id" name="state_id">
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">second</option>
    <option value="3">third</option>
    <option value="4">forth</option>
</select>
```

i don't know why this code not runnig.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#state_id').change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

this is sample and simple code . i check this on another project and face this problem.
thanks.

Comment: your res html has `#state_id` and you are referencing to a wrong id `'#country_id'`

Comment: What is the value of `result` in the ajax call?? Is it null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({url:'res.html',type:"POST",data:'',success:function(result){
                    $("#responsediv").html(result);
                }
            });
            $(document).on('change', '#country_id', function(){
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        });
</script>
```

note:

```
you don't need two doc ready handlers.
```

try this and see if this helps.

Comment: @aya Well i checked it on my localhost and it is working great! Getting all the values **1 2 3 4**.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the select box for countries in your HTML. Try modifying as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({url:'res.html',type:"POST",data:'',success:function(result){
                        $("#responsediv").html(result);
                    }
                });

                $('#country_id').change(function(){
                    alert($(this).val());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="country_id">
            <option value="0">Select Country...</option>
            <option value="1">Country One</option>
            <option value="2">Country Two</option>
        </select>
        <div id="responsediv">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi friend. i edit my code and #country_id should change to #state_id to my code but this problem exsist.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an element in your html that `$('#country_id')` would reference.